# How to load RTF Text from database and display it in data template in a Datagrid? WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik, richtextbox, radgridview

I'm trying to load RTF text from database and display it into datatemplate of custom RichTextBox .
I would like to get the text with style , with code the matter is simple but when I'm trying to use `<GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate> <GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate/>` , it got difficult

- Xaml code:

  ```
    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding document}"  Width="*" x:Name="Description"  IsReadOnly="True">
                <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate >
                        <local:UC_Description  x:Name="richtext">
                        </local:UC_Description>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
  ```
- C# code:

  ```
        List= new Controller().GetAll();

        foreach (Model item in List)
        {
            RtfFormatProvider provider = new RtfFormatProvider();
            DocumentFormatProvidersManager.RegisterFormatProvider(provider);
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(item.Description);
            document = provider.Import(byteArray);
            FlowDocument flow = new FlowDocument();

        }
        GridViewList.ItemsSource = null;
        GridViewList.ItemsSource = List;         


        this.DataContext = this;


    }

    public RadDocument ImportXaml(string content)
    {
        RtfFormatProvider provider = new RtfFormatProvider();
        return provider.Import(text);
    }
    public string RtfToPlainText(string rtf)
    {
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(rtf);
        var flowDocument = new FlowDocument();
        TextRange tr;
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArray))
        {

           tr = new TextRange(flowDocument.ContentStart, flowDocument.ContentEnd);
           tr.Load(ms, DataFormats.Rtf);
        }

        return tr.Text;
    }
  ```

How can I display text from RTF content in a data template?

Comment: What is `UC_Description` and what does the `document` properry return? Your sample code doesn't make much sense.

Comment: I registered data in the database via RichTextBox and I want to load this contents in datgridview cell

Comment: You didn't answer my question. You have put a `UC_Description` in the cell. Why? What is this? And what is `document` that you are trying to bind to?

Comment: `UC_Description` is a user control that define custom RichtextBox, the document that existed in the database has an RTF type.

Comment: You cannot get a reference to the `RichTextBox` until it has actually been created. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

A template is a template and there is no `UC_Description` or `RichTextBox` until it has been applied at runtime.

What you could do is to handle the `Loaded` event for the `UserControl` and then set the `Document` property of the `RichTextBox` to your document:

**XAML:**

```
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate >
        <local:UC_Description Loaded="OnLoaded" />
    </DataTemplate>
</telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
```

**Code:**

```
private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    UC_Description uc = (UC_Description)sender;
    uc.richTextBox.Document = ...;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, the name of the event handler is `OnLoaded`. It's the one that you hook up in the XAML markup of the template. I edited my answer.